# debezium could not access file "decoderbufs" using postgres 11 with default plugin pgoutput

Tags: apache-kafka, debezium

I'm new to kafka, I'm trying to use the debezium postgres connector. 
but even using postgres version 11 with the standard plugin I get this error:
org.apache.kafka.connect.errors.ConnectException: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: could not access file "decoderbufs": No such file or directory

To run kafka / debezium I'm using the image of the fast-data-dev docker as you can see below

```
  # this is our kafka cluster.
  kafka-cluster:
    image: landoop/fast-data-dev:latest
    environment:
      ADV_HOST: 127.0.0.1         # Change to 192.168.99.100 if using Docker Toolbox
      RUNTESTS: 0                 # Disable Running tests so the cluster starts faster
    ports:
      - 2181:2181                 # Zookeeper
      - 3030:3030                 # Landoop UI
      - 8081-8083:8081-8083       # REST Proxy, Schema Registry, Kafka Connect ports
      - 9581-9585:9581-9585       # JMX Ports
      - 9092:9092                 # Kafka Broker
```

after running i can open my localhost: 3030 to choose the debezium connector, i configured it this way:

[image]

and I'm using aws postgres rds in version 11.5
I saw several tutorials using wal2json, but I didn't find it in rds.extensions and didn't see a way to add it. Anyway, as of version 10, debezium can use pgoutput and apparently no configuration is necessary.

the rds.logical_replication property is set to 1
when executing SHOW wal_level; in the terminal I see that it returns logical
in the documentation says that you have to set max_wal_senders = 1 and max_replication_slots = 1
put in the rds the minimum `is 5, so I left the default that` is 10

I did not define the role REPLICATION because from what I understand in the rds there is no way

in this image you can see the version used is 11.5

[image]

but I get the error as you can see below

[image]

Comment: I found the problem, there was an option that I clicked and showed all the values, many defaults that were already filled, the plugin.name was with decoderbufs, it was just switching to pqoutput that worked

Comment: "plugin.name": "pgoutput"

Comment: @DaviResio where did you find the "plugin.name" option?

Comment: @ Vikrant Goel the problem was this, i was not finding this option. I found and put pgoutput. thanks

Answer (score 54, accepted):

You haven't set ***"plugin.name"*** property to ***"pgoutput"*** in your Debezium [connector properties](https://debezium.io/documentation/reference/1.1/connectors/postgresql.html#postgresql-connector-properties) which you've already figured out. But this answer is for others who don't know where to set this option and for more clarity.

In the following connector properties:

[image]

As you haven't set *plugin.name* option it is taking the default value which is *decoderbufs* and that's why you were getting the following error:

[image]

Setting the **"plugin.name"** explicitly to **"pgoutput"** should solve the issue.

```
{ 
  "connector.class": "io.debezium.connector.postgresql.PostgresConnector", 
  "database.user": "postgres",
  "database.dbname": "xxxxx",
  "tasks.max": "1", 
  "database.hostname": "xxxx.rds.amazonaws.com", 
  "database.password": "xxxx", 
  "database.server.name": "database-1",
  "database.port": "5432",
  "plugin.name": "pgoutput" --> this property
}
```