# CDC with WSO2 Streaming Integrator and Postgres DB

Tags: postgresql, siddhi, cdc, debezium

I am trying to setup Change Data Capture (CDC) between WSO2 Streaming Integrator and a local Postgres DB.

I have added the Postgres Driver (v42.2.5) to *SI_HOME/lib* and I am able to read data from the database from a Siddhi application.

I am following the [CDCWithListeningMode](https://ei.docs.wso2.com/en/latest/streaming-integrator/samples/CDCWithListeningMode/) example to implement CDC and I am using **pgoutput** as the logical decoding plugin. But when I run the application I get the following log.

```
    [2020-04-23_19-02-37_460] INFO {org.apache.kafka.connect.json.JsonConverterConfig} - JsonConverterConfig values: 
    converter.type = key
    schemas.cache.size = 1000
    schemas.enable = true

[2020-04-23_19-02-37_461] INFO {org.apache.kafka.connect.json.JsonConverterConfig} - JsonConverterConfig values: 
    converter.type = value
    schemas.cache.size = 1000
    schemas.enable = false

[2020-04-23_19-02-37_461] INFO {io.debezium.embedded.EmbeddedEngine$EmbeddedConfig} - EmbeddedConfig values: 
    access.control.allow.methods = 
    access.control.allow.origin = 
    bootstrap.servers = [localhost:9092]
    header.converter = class org.apache.kafka.connect.storage.SimpleHeaderConverter
    internal.key.converter = class org.apache.kafka.connect.json.JsonConverter
    internal.value.converter = class org.apache.kafka.connect.json.JsonConverter
    key.converter = class org.apache.kafka.connect.json.JsonConverter
    listeners = null
    metric.reporters = []
    metrics.num.samples = 2
    metrics.recording.level = INFO
    metrics.sample.window.ms = 30000
    offset.flush.interval.ms = 60000
    offset.flush.timeout.ms = 5000
    offset.storage.file.filename = 
    offset.storage.partitions = null
    offset.storage.replication.factor = null
    offset.storage.topic = 
    plugin.path = null
    rest.advertised.host.name = null
    rest.advertised.listener = null
    rest.advertised.port = null
    rest.host.name = null
    rest.port = 8083
    ssl.client.auth = none
    task.shutdown.graceful.timeout.ms = 5000
    value.converter = class org.apache.kafka.connect.json.JsonConverter

[2020-04-23_19-02-37_516] INFO {io.debezium.connector.common.BaseSourceTask} -    offset.storage = io.siddhi.extension.io.cdc.source.listening.InMemoryOffsetBackingStore 
[2020-04-23_19-02-37_517] INFO {io.debezium.connector.common.BaseSourceTask} -    database.server.name = localhost_5432 
[2020-04-23_19-02-37_517] INFO {io.debezium.connector.common.BaseSourceTask} -    database.port = 5432 
[2020-04-23_19-02-37_517] INFO {io.debezium.connector.common.BaseSourceTask} -    table.whitelist = SweetProductionTable 
[2020-04-23_19-02-37_517] INFO {io.debezium.connector.common.BaseSourceTask} -    cdc.source.object = 1716717434 
[2020-04-23_19-02-37_517] INFO {io.debezium.connector.common.BaseSourceTask} -    database.hostname = localhost 
[2020-04-23_19-02-37_518] INFO {io.debezium.connector.common.BaseSourceTask} -    database.password = ******** 
[2020-04-23_19-02-37_518] INFO {io.debezium.connector.common.BaseSourceTask} -    name = CDCWithListeningModeinsertSweetProductionStream 
[2020-04-23_19-02-37_518] INFO {io.debezium.connector.common.BaseSourceTask} -    server.id = 6140 
[2020-04-23_19-02-37_519] INFO {io.debezium.connector.common.BaseSourceTask} -    database.history = io.debezium.relational.history.FileDatabaseHistory 
[2020-04-23_19-02-38_103] INFO {io.debezium.connector.postgresql.PostgresConnectorTask} - user 'user_name' connected to database 'db_name' on PostgreSQL 11.5, compiled by Visual C++ build 1914, 64-bit with roles:
    role 'user_name' [superuser: false, replication: true, inherit: true, create role: false, create db: false, can log in: true] (Encoded) 
[2020-04-23_19-02-38_104] INFO {io.debezium.connector.postgresql.PostgresConnectorTask} - No previous offset found 
[2020-04-23_19-02-38_104] INFO {io.debezium.connector.postgresql.PostgresConnectorTask} - Taking a new snapshot of the DB and streaming logical changes once the snapshot is finished... 
[2020-04-23_19-02-38_105] INFO {io.debezium.util.Threads} - Requested thread factory for connector PostgresConnector, id = localhost_5432 named = records-snapshot-producer 
[2020-04-23_19-02-38_105] INFO {io.debezium.util.Threads} - Requested thread factory for connector PostgresConnector, id = localhost_5432 named = records-stream-producer 
[2020-04-23_19-02-38_293] INFO {io.debezium.connector.postgresql.connection.PostgresConnection} - Obtained valid replication slot ReplicationSlot [active=false, latestFlushedLSN=null] 
[2020-04-23_19-02-38_704] ERROR {io.siddhi.core.stream.input.source.Source} - Error on 'CDCWithListeningMode'. Connection to the database lost. Error while connecting at Source 'cdc' at 'insertSweetProductionStream'. Will retry in '5 sec'. (Encoded) 
io.siddhi.core.exception.ConnectionUnavailableException: Connection to the database lost.
    at io.siddhi.extension.io.cdc.source.CDCSource.lambda$connect$1(CDCSource.java:424)
    at io.debezium.embedded.EmbeddedEngine.run(EmbeddedEngine.java:793)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834)
Caused by: org.apache.kafka.connect.errors.ConnectException: Cannot create replication connection
    at io.debezium.connector.postgresql.connection.PostgresReplicationConnection.(PostgresReplicationConnection.java:87)
    at io.debezium.connector.postgresql.connection.PostgresReplicationConnection.(PostgresReplicationConnection.java:38)
    at io.debezium.connector.postgresql.connection.PostgresReplicationConnection$ReplicationConnectionBuilder.build(PostgresReplicationConnection.java:362)
    at io.debezium.connector.postgresql.PostgresTaskContext.createReplicationConnection(PostgresTaskContext.java:65)
    at io.debezium.connector.postgresql.RecordsStreamProducer.(RecordsStreamProducer.java:81)
    at io.debezium.connector.postgresql.RecordsSnapshotProducer.(RecordsSnapshotProducer.java:70)
    at io.debezium.connector.postgresql.PostgresConnectorTask.createSnapshotProducer(PostgresConnectorTask.java:133)
    at io.debezium.connector.postgresql.PostgresConnectorTask.start(PostgresConnectorTask.java:86)
    at io.debezium.connector.common.BaseSourceTask.start(BaseSourceTask.java:45)
    at io.debezium.embedded.EmbeddedEngine.run(EmbeddedEngine.java:677)
    ... 3 more
Caused by: io.debezium.jdbc.JdbcConnectionException: ERROR: could not access file "decoderbufs": No such file or directory
    at io.debezium.connector.postgresql.connection.PostgresReplicationConnection.initReplicationSlot(PostgresReplicationConnection.java:145)
    at io.debezium.connector.postgresql.connection.PostgresReplicationConnection.(PostgresReplicationConnection.java:79)
    ... 12 more
Caused by: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: could not access file "decoderbufs": No such file or directory
    at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.receiveErrorResponse(QueryExecutorImpl.java:2440)
    at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.processResults(QueryExecutorImpl.java:2183)
    at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.execute(QueryExecutorImpl.java:308)
    at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgStatement.executeInternal(PgStatement.java:441)
    at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgStatement.execute(PgStatement.java:365)
    at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgStatement.executeWithFlags(PgStatement.java:307)
    at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgStatement.executeCachedSql(PgStatement.java:293)
    at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgStatement.executeWithFlags(PgStatement.java:270)
    at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgStatement.execute(PgStatement.java:266)
    at org.postgresql.replication.fluent.logical.LogicalCreateSlotBuilder.make(LogicalCreateSlotBuilder.java:48)
    at io.debezium.connector.postgresql.connection.PostgresReplicationConnection.initReplicationSlot(PostgresReplicationConnection.java:108)
    ... 13 more
```

Debezium defaults to decoderbufs plugin - "*could not access file "decoderbufs": No such file or directory*".

According to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61371696/9454632), the issue is due to the configuration of decoderbufs plugin.

**Details**

1. Postgres - 11.4
2. siddhi-cdc-io - 2.0.3
3. Debezium - 0.8.3

How do I configure the embedded debezium engine to use the pgoutput plugin? Will changing this configuration fix the error?

Please help me with this issue. I have not found any resources that can help me.

Answer (score 0):

you either need to update the Debezium to the latest 1.1 version - this will enable you to use `pgoutput` plugin using `plugin.name` config option or you need to deploy (and maybe build) `decoderbufs.so` library to your PostgreSQL database.

I'd recommend the former as 0.8.3 is very old version.

Answer (score 0):

I observed this behavior with PostgreSQL 12 when I tried to do CDC with **pgoutput** logical decoding output plug-in. It seems like even though I configured the database with **pgoutput**, the siddhi extension is trying to make the connection using "decoderbufs" as decoding plug-in.

When I tried configuring **decoderbufs** as the logical decoding output plug-in in the database level, I was able to use siddhi io extension without any issue.

It seems like for now, Siddhi io CDC only supports **decoderbufs** logical decoding output plug-in with PostgreSQL.